# Javascript animation lags

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Since I started studying web development 2 months ago, I've had similar problem. 
The animation lag. This is the only animation and sometimes when it triggers it's kinda low in fps. I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showSidebar(){
        $("#sidebar").stop().show('slide',{easing:"easeOutQuart", direction:"left"}, 1000);
        $("#sidebar-ctn").delay(100).stop().show('slide',{easing:"easeOutQuart", direction:"left"}, 900);
    }
    function hideSidebar(){
        $("#sidebar").stop().hide('slide',{easing:"easeOutQuart",  direction:"left"}, 500);
        $("#sidebar-ctn").stop().hide('slide',{easing:"easeOutQuart",   direction:"left"}, 400);
    }
   </script>
```

I guess there's something wrong because I don't experience fps drops (i'm not sure what the right term, just that the animation is lagging) in other website with so many animations like this:
http://sarasoueidan.com/demos/windows8-animations/

UPDATE:
So I have discovered what causes it and it's the amount of buttons I have.
Here's what it looks like.
[image]

The sidebar has a windows 8 inspired animation and it's the one that lags.

when I test it for framerate here's the result:
[image]

but when I removed the circular buttons:
[image]

Here's the css for my buttons:

```
#tables button{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    outline: none;

    width: 105px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 70px;

    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(120,155,179,0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-border-radius:100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this, that it won't affect the performance even with so much buttons?

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle? Are you sure this is animation that makes page lags, and not any other thing on the page?! Anyway, jQuery animations are well known to be quite 'slow'

Comment: Even I face problem when the load on browser is very high, and the graphic performance of a computer is low. It's just normal.. :)

Comment: you linked to a demo the explicitly has a link to a tutorial,why dont you read the tutorial first? because it doesnt seem you have read it.with the code you're showing.

Comment: JavaScript animations will never be as fast ("smooth"/high fps) as a native solution. This is why we now have CSS animation.

Comment: CSS is not always faster than javascript. Here is a good article about it. http://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/

Comment: @A.Wolff i tried to provide but, my jquery won't work. First time using jsfiddle.

Comment: @mpm I put the link there just to compare it with my work, although it has so many animations, I experience no animation lag there while I experience lag in my work.

Comment: @2pha Even this is a great article, this doesn't really compare CSS3 animation performance vs javascript one (for not complex animation). To set CSS3 animation, they are using zepto, i'm not sure then how we can compare it here. But as GASP team is an expert team regarding this and i'm not, i won't open a debate here. Looks like more comparing jQuery vs zepto vs GASP animations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kinda late but I manage to lessen the fps drop significantly by using spans instead of buttons. It was the large number of buttons that made it cumbersome after all.